# Parse JSON object in Flatlist React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in React Native , I am developing an application like Ecommerce App, I am using Woocommerce (Wordpress) as backend and through Woocomrce Api response I am trying to implement in my React Native App, but I have one problem while parsing JSON. Basically I don't konw how to parse images array in flatlist. My code and API response are mentioned below, I remind you that `item.images[0].src` is not working.
Thank you in advance.

**My Woocommerce  API Response**

```
{
  "id": 794,
  "name": "Premium Quality",
  "slug": "premium-quality-19",
  "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-19/",
  "date_created": "2017-03-23T17:01:14",
  "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
  "date_modified": "2017-03-23T17:01:14",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
  "type": "simple",
  "status": "publish",
  "featured": false,
  "catalog_visibility": "visible",
  "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
  "short_description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>\n",
  "sku": "",
  "price": "21.99",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "sale_price": "",
  "date_on_sale_from": null,
  "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
  "date_on_sale_to": null,
  "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
  "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#36;</span>21.99</span>",
  "on_sale": false,
  "purchasable": true,
  "total_sales": 0,
  "virtual": false,
  "downloadable": false,
  "downloads": [],
  "download_limit": -1,
  "download_expiry": -1,
  "external_url": "",
  "button_text": "",
  "tax_status": "taxable",
  "tax_class": "",
  "manage_stock": false,
  "stock_quantity": null,
  "stock_status": "instock",
  "backorders": "no",
  "backorders_allowed": false,
  "backordered": false,
  "sold_individually": false,
  "weight": "",
  "dimensions": {
    "length": "",
    "width": "",
    "height": ""
  },
  "shipping_required": true,
  "shipping_taxable": true,
  "shipping_class": "",
  "shipping_class_id": 0,
  "reviews_allowed": true,
  "average_rating": "0.00",
  "rating_count": 0,
  "related_ids": [
    53,
    40,
    56,
    479,
    99
  ],
  "upsell_ids": [],
  "cross_sell_ids": [],
  "parent_id": 0,
  "purchase_note": "",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Clothing",
      "slug": "clothing"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "T-shirts",
      "slug": "t-shirts"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [],
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 792,
      "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:01:13",
      "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:13",
      "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:01:13",
      "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:13",
      "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front-4.jpg",
      "name": "",
      "alt": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 793,
      "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:01:14",
      "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
      "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:01:14",
      "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:01:14",
      "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_back-2.jpg",
      "name": "",
      "alt": ""
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [],
  "default_attributes": [],
  "variations": [],
  "grouped_products": [],
  "menu_order": 0,
  "meta_data": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/794"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My APP.js Code**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Image, Dimensions, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, FlatList } from 'react-native';
    import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-woocommerce-api';

var WooCommerceApp = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: 'http://store.oruga.in/', // Your store URL
    ssl: true,
    consumerKey: 'ck_113e04d8a91ce34cbfeaf21971b6d5e18e7XXXXX', // Your consumer secret
    consumerSecret: 'cs_fd0f4b6a5573837b1f7732a98dccb355a233XXXXX', // Your consumer secret
    wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
    version: 'wc/v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    queryStringAuth: true
});

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            responsedata: [],
            loading: true
        };
        WooCommerceApp.get('products/')
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ responsedata: data }, () => {
                    this.setState({ loading: false });
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar hidden />
                {this.state.loading === true ? (
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0f3443" />
                    </View>
                ) : (
                        <View>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.responsedata}
                                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                    <View>
                                        <Image source={{ uri: item.images[0].src }} />
                                        <Text >{item.name}</Text>
                                    </View>

                                )} />
                        </View>)
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know this is an old question but the answer might be helpful for others like me.
i had also came across this situation when using WC api.
the solution is to use

`const image = item.images.slice(0,1).pop();` to get the first object from the inner image array and display it using

```
 <Image
        source={{ uri: image.src }}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
        style={{flex:1, width: '100%', height: 150 }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array as data to your `FlatList`, in your example you passed a JSON object to your flatlist that's why it doesn't render any thing. Also you should pass height and width to you image or it will not show.

Change your flatlist like this and it should work.

```
<View>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.responsedata.images}
    keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: item.src }} />
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View>

    )}
  />
</View>
```

Other thing, don't call setState in your constructor, it will show you a warning. Move the api call to `componentDidMount` function:

```
componentDidMount() {
  WooCommerceApp.get('products/')
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ responsedata: data }, () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Edit:**
If you need the response json then you don't need FlatList, FlatList is to show a List of items. And if you want to show only first image then change your FlatList like this

```
<Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: this.state.responsedata.images[0].src }} />
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but Brother i want all jsonresposnse and only first image

Comment: FlatList allow to show a list, so can't pass an object as data. I edited my answer with code to show only first image

Comment: still not resolve bro, I want all data and first image of every product

Comment: I didn't get what do you want to show! In your question I see that Woocommerce API returns an object not an array, so which data you need to extract from this object?

Comment: i want to exctract name,regular_price, and first image of each product  to show in home screen.(but images itself as an object hence it is not parse by flatlist) plase refer my My Woocommerce API Response

Comment: In the solution you provided in your question, does product name gets shown on the screen? if yes then try to add style prop to `Image` with height and width like I did in my answer

Comment: Can you tell how to add props?? Please

Comment: Like you did in the example in your question just replace `<Image source={{ uri: item.images[0].src }} />` with `<Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: item.images[0].src }} />`

Comment: i tried but it gives error [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.images[0].src')]